# Insertion Sort?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures

So our teacher gave us this code for bubble sort

```
public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxSize = 100;
        ArrayBubble arr;
        arr = new ArrayBubble(maxSize);
        arr.insert(77);
        arr.insert(99);
        arr.insert(44);
        arr.insert(55);
        arr.insert(22);
        arr.insert(88);
        arr.insert(11);
        arr.insert(00);
        arr.insert(66);
        arr.insert(33);
        arr.display();
        arr.bubbleSort();
        arr.display();
    }
}
class ArrayBubble {
    private int[] list;
    private int nItems;
    public ArrayBubble(int max) {
        list = new int[max];
        nItems = 0;
    }
    public void insert(int value) {
        list[nItems] = value;
        nItems++;
    }
    public void display() {
        for (int j = 0; j < nItems; j++)
        System.out.print(list[j] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    public void bubbleSort() {
        int out, in ;
        for (out = nItems - 1; out > 1; out--)
        for ( in = 0; in < out; in ++)
        if (list[ in ] > list[ in +1]) swap( in , in +1);
    }
    public void swap(int one, int two) {
        int temp = list[one];
        list[one] = list[two];
        list[two] = temp;
    }
}
```

Then she asked us to modify this and make an insertion sorting with this snippet code

```
public void insertionSort() {
    int out, in ;
    for (out = 1; out < nItems; out++) {
        double temp = arr[out]; in = out;
        while ( in > 0 && arr[ in -1] >= temp) {
            arr[ in ] = a[ in -1];
            -- in ;
        }
        arr[ in ] = temp;
    }
}
```

Here's the output of the bubble sort.. so if i modify it to insertion it should have the same output.

```
77 99 44 55 22 88 11 0 66 33 
0 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99
```

Process completed.

I tried to replace the bubble sorting code with this code and rename arr.bubbleSort to arr.insertionSort but still wont work.
Can anyone help?? Thank you. (:

Comment: @Bombe, all homework questions don't deserve a close vote... She has clearly put it effort and asks help when it didnt produce correct result..

Comment: It's be helpful if you could specify "it still wont work". What error message do you receive?

Comment: @Codebender I think they do deserve closing; their teacher is paid to be available for questions of this kind.

Comment: I agree with Bombe. The code provided by your teacher is awfully written. You just have to change some variable names and add it to your `ArrayBubble` class. Take the time to do it, practice and learn.

Comment: @gefei it don't sort..it just display the same thing..


77 99 44 55 22 88 11 0 66 33 
77 99 44 55 22 88 11 0 66 33

Comment: I tried your code. Insertion sort works fine. Maybe you forgot to change `arr.bubbleSort();` to `arr.insertionSort();`?

Comment: @gefei it shows..

E:\COPRO codes\InsertionSort.java:52: class, interface, or enum expected
    public void  insertionSort()
           ^

Comment: I did change it to `arr.insertionSort();`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you clearly need to add a method in the class `ArrayBubble` to implement insertion sort. I made some modification to your code, since it did not compile. For the problems see comment

```
 public void insertionSort() {
        int out, in ;
        for (out = 1; out < nItems; out++) {
            int temp = list[out]; in = out; // -- temp should be int, since your list is an array of int. and your array is called list, not arr
            while ( in > 0 && list[ in -1] >= temp) {
                list[ in ] = list[ in -1];
                --in ;
            }
            list[ in ] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Then you need to modify your `main` method in `BubbleSort` to call `insertionSort`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxSize = 100;
        ArrayBubble arr;
        arr = new ArrayBubble(maxSize);
        arr.insert(77);
        arr.insert(99);
        arr.insert(44);
        arr.insert(55);
        arr.insert(22);
        arr.insert(88);
        arr.insert(11);
        arr.insert(00);
        arr.insert(66);
        arr.insert(33);
        arr.display();
        //arr.bubbleSort();
        arr.insertionSort();
        arr.display();
    }
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my solution for insertion sort. 
int[] input = { 5, 3, 2, 21, 70, 17, 2, 5, 19, 11 };
int[] result = insertionSort(input);

private static int[] insertionSort(int[] input) {
    if (input == null) {                                // if array is null, print this is a null array
        System.out.println("null array");
    } else if (input.length < 2) {                      // if array is empty or has 1 element, no need to sort, will return as is
        System.out.println("already sorted: ");
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {        // begin with the second element and iterate until the end
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {          // from beginning until j will be already sorted
                if (input[j] > input[i]) {              // if index is less then the previous, swap and continue until the beginning of the list
                    swapWithPrev(input, i);             
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}

private static void swapWithPrev(int[] input, int index) {
    int temp = input[index - 1];
    input[index - 1] = input[index];
    input[index] = temp;
}
```